# Is there Windows 8 x64 System Repair Disc ISO I can download?

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, system-repair-disc

I managed to crash my Windows 8 x64 machine *while creating the system repair disc* -- now it crashes on boot.  Anyone know where/if I can get a system repair disk ISO I can burn with another computer?  I recently upgraded, and went with the no-media "download and install" option.  Whoops!

Comment: That irony ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a project for Repair disks for Vista. Sadly this appears to have been discontinued now due to legal reasons. You could redownload your Windows OS disk from Microsoft or use the disk that came with your computer. It will work in the same way.

Have a look at: [How to create a Windows repair disk](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/11/01/how-to-create-a-windows-8-system-repair-disc/) and [this](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-create-recovery-media-144098)

[How do I Redownload Windows 8](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1117133-how-do-i-redownload-my-3999-windows-8-back-up-disk-still-not-here/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I went with the "download and install" option, when upgrading.  I'll update my question to reflect this.  I've been so focused on the repair disk, I forgot to look around for the install media, which should do fairly well too.

Comment: Download and install (unless you clicked save nothing) should have saved a file called "Windows.iso" to your computer, otherwise you may have to rebuild it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I saved nothing.  My bad!  On a side note, I was basically doing the how-to you linked when this happened. :P

Comment: Let me know if it works. I think it is the most convenient solution.